# Failed attempts at natural sort in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I'm trying to achieve *natural/alphanumeric sorting in MySQL* and having no luck. I have read several Stack articles and various articles on the topic I found in google searches. Here is the basic query I began with:

```
select VideoTitle, VideoID
from Filters
where VideoSource = 'Netflix'
and IMDBSeries = 'tt0367279'
and PublishDate is not null
ORDER BY VideoTitle
```

That query yields this result set:

> ```
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 1 Pilot
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 10 Pier Pressure
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 2 Top Banana
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 3 Bringing Up Buster
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 4 Key Decisions
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 5 Charity Drive
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 6 Visiting Ours
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 7 In God We Trust
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 8 My Mother, the Car
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 9 Storming the Castle
> ```

Notice this row is out of order from a natural sorting perspective:

> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 10 Pier Pressure

Based on the posts/articles I read, I have also tried these approaches, with their accompanying result sets:

```
select VideoTitle
from Filters
where VideoSource = 'Netflix'
and IMDBSeries = 'tt0367279'
and PublishDate is not null
ORDER BY CAST(VideoTitle AS UNSIGNED), VideoTitle
```

> ```
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 1 Pilot
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 10 Pier Pressure
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 2 Top Banana
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 3 Bringing Up Buster
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 4 Key Decisions
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 5 Charity Drive
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 6 Visiting Ours
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 7 In God We Trust
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 8 My Mother, the Car
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 9 Storming the Castle
> ```

---

```
select VideoTitle
from Filters
where VideoSource = 'Netflix'
and IMDBSeries = 'tt0367279'
and PublishDate is not null
ORDER BY LENGTH(VideoTitle), VideoTitle
```

> ```
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 1 Pilot
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 2 Top Banana
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 4 Key Decisions
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 5 Charity Drive
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 6 Visiting Ours
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 10 Pier Pressure
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 7 In God We Trust
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 3 Bringing Up Buster
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 8 My Mother, the Car
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 9 Storming the Castle
> ```

---

```
select VideoTitle
from Filters
where VideoSource = 'Netflix'
and IMDBSeries = 'tt0367279'
and PublishDate is not null
ORDER BY VideoTitle + 0 ASC
```

> ```
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 1 Pilot
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 9 Storming the Castle
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 8 My Mother, the Car
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 7 In God We Trust
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 6 Visiting Ours
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 5 Charity Drive
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 4 Key Decisions
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 3 Bringing Up Buster
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 2 Top Banana
> Arrested Development Season 1: Ep. 10 Pier Pressure
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is your mysql version?

Comment: I would recommend you to add two more INT columns on your database, season and epNumber. It would solve all your problems in a heart beat.

Comment: Thank you Jorge. You're right, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to store the show title, the season, the episode number, and the episode title in separate columns.

In this case, you might be able to do some string manipulation to get what you need.

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(VideoTitle, ': ', -1), ' ', 2), ' ', -1)+0
```

This is such a fragile solution, though.

Comment: Thank you Bill. Works perfectly. I'll see if I can add some columns and get this better at the DB level.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you can sort this by piece:

```
order by substring_index(VideoTitle, ' Season ', 1),
         substring_index(VideoTitle, ' Season ', -1) + 0,
         substring_index(VideoTitle, ': Ep. ', -1) + 0
```

This assumes that the string `' Season '` an `: Ep.` only occur once in each title.

The following version should also be pretty close, assuming seasons have only one digit:

```
order by substring_index(VideoTitle, ': Ep. ', 1),
         substring_index(VideoTitle, ': Ep. ', -1) + 0
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your well-thought solution.

Answer (score 1):

If creating new columns for making your model better searchable I would go with a more elegant solution than having to break down the string by pieces.

```
select VideoTitle 
  from (select VideoTitle, 
               VideoTitle REGEXP '.+Ep\\. [0-9]{2}.+' vd2dig 
          from videos
       ) sub
 order by vd2dig, VideoTitle;
```

This will essentially make `VideoTitle` when having two digits to `1` and when it has one digit it will be `0` so I order by this column first then the natural order on `VideoTitle`

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6abde/1

Comment: Thank you Jorge for your well-thought solution.